# In ReactJS, Select has Span as a child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code

```
<div className="formInput">
  <label>Featured</label>
  <select id="featured" onChange={handleChange}>
    <option value={false}>No</option>
    <option value={true}>Yes</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div className="selectRooms">
  <label>Rooms</label>
  <select id="rooms" multiple onChange={handleSelect}>
    {loading
      ? <CircularProgress />
      : data && data.map((room) => (
        <option key={room._id} value={room._id}>
          {room.title}
        </option>
      ))
    }
  </select>
</div>
```

It is showing error this :-

[image: in this image i'm getting this error]

How can this dom validation error be fixed? It says in my code that I have span as a child of select, but I didn't use span in my code. I tried to configure it but can't get it to work...

Comment: Quick hunch is that either `loading` or `data` contains text string which is then parsed as such and wrapped in **span** by default. Hence you should convert them to booleans with `!!loading` and `!!data` when you have such conditions

Comment: Where is `span` in your given code ?

Comment: I didn't get it please explain it me

Comment: i didn't use span

Comment: Try to remove `<CircularProgress />` from inside `select`. Does problem resolve ? Because `<CircularProgress />` contains `span`. We know we only have to use `<option>` inside `<select>`.

Comment: My guess is that the `CircularProgress` component is using a `span` as its outer-most element. Hardcode the `CircularProgress` to always render and inspect the DOM to verify/validate any `span` element. Can you share what `CircularProgress` component is? Where it comes from?

Comment: Can you share your JavaScript code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, a `span` element cannot be a child of the `select` element. Even though you aren't rendering a `span` yourself explicitly you can see from the code stacktrace that the `CircularProgress` component *is* rendering a `span`.

[`select` element technical summary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#technical_summary)

> **Permitted content** Zero or more `<option>` or `<optgroup>` elements.

Since you can't wrap `CircularProgress` in anything to make it a valid child of `select`, I suggest refactoring the code a bit to conditionally render the `CircularProgress` component ***or*** the entire `select`.

Example:

```
<div className="selectRooms">
  {loading ? (
    <CircularProgress />
  ) : (
    <label>
      Rooms
      <select id="rooms" multiple onChange={handleSelect}>
        {data?.map((room) => (
          <option key={room._id} value={room._id}>
            {room.title}
          </option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </label>
  )}
</div>
```

[image: Edit select-is-showing-span-as-a-child-in-reactjs]